# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'customer_id' for Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Customer, Item and Order model. Customer has_many Items through Orders and has_many Orders. Item has_many Customers through Orders and has_many Orders. Order belongs to Customer and Item. I get the `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'customer_id' for Order.` error when trying to save through the console:

**Customer** model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :items, through: :orders

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

**Item** model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :customers, through: :orders
end
```

**Order** model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

**Orders** table:

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :customers, index: true
      t.belongs_to :items, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**Console Command to save Order**
(note that cuban_sandwich and chris are saved as a new Customer and Item already.)

`order1 = chris.orders.build(customers_id: chris.id, items_id: cuban_sandwich.id)`

Could I be saving this incorrectly? Or is there a problem with my model/table associations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to your migration. These lines:

```
t.belongs_to :customers, index: true
t.belongs_to :items, index: true
```

create fields called `customers_id` and `items_id`, not `customer_id` and `items_id` (note singular vs. plural).

A belongs-to association is a to-one relationship, so it should be singular, `customer_id`.

Roll back your migration with `rake db:rollback` and change the two `belongs_to` calls to be `customer` and `item`.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you have `customer_id` column on `orders` table

```
rails g migration AddCustomerIdToOrders customer_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Also, I don't believe you need to put the `customers_id` as it will be filled in when the association is made. Also you need to use `create` not `build`

instead of this

```
order1 = chris.orders.build(customers_id: chris.id, items_id: cuban_sandwich.id)
```

try this

```
order1 = chris.orders.create(items_id: cuban_sandwich.id)
```

Comment: Sorry i missed that part of your error. I've updated my answer to solve that too

Comment: `#<Order customers_id: nil, items_id: 2, created_at: "2016-02-25 02:11:08", updated_at: "2016-02-25 02:11:08", customer_id: 1>`

Should I remove the t.belongs_to :customers, index: true ?